# Connecting SharePoint in Java

Tags: java, http, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I am trying to connect to the SharePoint from my java code. However there seems to be something is missing and I am not able to connect to the sharepoint.

I am using the below code,

```
    NtlmAuthenticator credentials = new NtlmAuthenticator("domain", "uname", "Password");

    // Initialize proxy settings
    //HttpProxy httpProxy = new HttpProxy("my_system_proxy", 80);

    // Connect to Sharepoint
    SPSite instance = new SPSite(new URL("https://my_url/cplc/projects/Knowledge%20Share/Forms/PracticeWise.aspx"), credentials, null, true, SPVersion.SP2013);

    // Get root web instance
    SPWeb rootWeb = instance.getRootWeb();

    // Get list of all lists and document libraries from root web
    SPListCollection lists = rootWeb.getLists();
```

I don't know what value I should set for proxy field there.

If I don't set the proxy and send null to it, it says   **"401: UnAuthorised"
             HTTP transport error: java.net.UnknownHostException: proxy.msa"**

**Update:**

I am referring this,

https://code.google.com/p/java-sharepoint-library/

Can anybody please help me to proceed further?

Comment: I think the problem is on credential type, try to change with NetworkCredential instance, maybe the Sharepoint 2013 has Kerberos ?

Comment: I didn't get you, can you please tell more?

Comment: Sharepoint can be configured with Ntlm or Kerberos Authentication, maybe your server have Kerberos and in your code on new SPSite you pass NtlmAuthentication, try to change the class (on .net there are NetworkCredential on Java I don't know ..)

Comment: How do I check if it is Ntlm or Kerberos?

Comment: See this [link](http://blog.blksthl.com/2012/09/26/the-first-kerberos-guide-for-sharepoint-2013-technicians/), also try to compile the project as x64.

Answer (score 0):

Even if this is not the answer to the question, I want to share with you a project i've just created to help otheres to integrate with sharepoint, as the problem you are into is the same i faced when trying to integrate java apps with sharepoint online. My first approach was to create a jni wrapper of a library made with c#, but this is a headache when you have linux machines in your company, as it will not work as it is based on native dlls method invocation.

I created a simple to use sharepoint java api that hope will help others to communicate with sharepoint

https://github.com/kikovalle/PLGSharepointRestAPI-java/

Also as the full implementation of the Rest API is not covered, you can feel free to contribute to the project.

Hope this will help and be usefull to save you time struggling with sharepoint integrations.